# how to fetch all links from html without ancore tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to fetch all links from the link given in code and particularly this  https://api.somthing.com/v1/companies/ link. All the regex which I found online is only fetching simple links like https://api.somthing.com

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.linkdin.com/'

x = requests.get(url)
html_doc=x.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"html.parser" )
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) the urls directly from the response [*content*](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.0.0/user/quickstart/#response-content) :

```
p= r'https://api\.something\.com/.*?(?=")'

urls = re.findall(p, html_doc)
```

​
Output :

```
['https://api.something.com/v1/companies/postings/733260034',
 'https://api.something.com/v1/companies/postings/371262356',
 'https://api.something.com/v1/companies/postings/465637233',
 'https://api.something.com/v1/companies/postings/315747724,
...
```

Comment: That's not what you ask for in your *question/post*. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: actually I want a regx which can fetch any type of url not any particular type of url.@Timeless

Comment: In this case, use `p = r'https://.+?\.com/.*?(?=")'`

Comment: If we are assuming that links are contained **only** in attributes, I believe your lookahead should be `(?="|')`.